# NetBeans plugin fails if nb-javac installed

Tags: netbeans, plugins, codenameone

Using NetBeans 11.1 with Java 11 on Linux (haven't tried on other platforms).

If I install the 'nb-javac' plugin, as recommended by the IDE notifications, the CodenameOne plugin module fails to load and therefore CodenameOne features are unavailable.

Any suggestions or workarounds?

Comment: This is a know bug: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2916

Comment: I use Netbeans 10 + Oracle Java 8 + CN1 plugin on Linux and they work fine. So a simple workaroud is the use of a previous version of Netbeans, if it's not a problem for you. However, for a proper solution, you can try to add a comment to https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/2916

Comment: @FrancescoGalgani I just downloaded the [11.0 Codename One plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/42406/codename-one) and installed it in NetBeans 11.1 with no problems at all. I am running on Windows 10. As noted in the bug report, the error is not necessarily reproducible.

Comment: Thanks @JoseHeitor I think this is the key we need to reproduce that issue. I've added a link to this post and moved it to the closer milestone release

Answer (score 3):

I am using Windows 10, NetBeans 12 and had the same problem.
I solved it by removing

- org-netbeans-modules-nbjavac.jar
- org-netbeans-modules-nbjavac-api.jar
- org-netbeans-modules-nbjavac-impl.jar
  files from directory C:\Users[USERNAME]\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\12.0\modules.
  After staring NB, it notifies that some modules are missing. You can click the link to install the lastest version. It worked for me.

I hope this will help someone.

Comment: Removing the files under <C:\Users[USERNAME]\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\12.1\modules> made the installation work for me with Netbeans 12.1.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Netbeans 12.0 on Windows. I installed the nb-javac plugin as suggested in the notifications, and then immediately after was unable to run my application. I use Java FX and Netbeans said it couldn't find the javafx.controls module. Deleting the three files from C:\Users[USERNAME]\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\12.1\module worked for me too.