# NetBeans 12.4 "Warning - could not install some modules: JavaFX wrapper"

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans

I get the following message after exiting out of NetBeans and then re-starting.

> Warning - could not install some modules: JavaFX wrapper - No module providing the capability org.openide.modules.jre.JavaFX could be found. Another module could not be installed due to the above problems.

I am using Java 15, with JavaFX. I didn't have the issue with 12.3 and Java 15, but now I get it at least once a day, depending on how often I leave and re-enter.

I have a work-around. I replace the NetBeans cache with a clean copy kept for this purpose, and I can then restart and continue working without the error, but this is a bit tedious after the first couple of times, each day.

```
Product Version: Apache NetBeans IDE 12.4
Java: 15.0.4; OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 15.0.4+5-MTS
Runtime: OpenJDK Runtime Environment 15.0.4+5-MTS
System: Windows 10 version 10.0 running on amd64; UTF8; en_AU (nb)
```

Comment: The only thing I could find with any reference to your issue was an old mail [thread](https://www.mail-archive.com/users@netbeans.apache.org/msg01403.html) mentioning that this symptom typically correlates with a non Oracle JDK, a circumstance which you share. The implied solution seems to be using the Oracle JDK, which for many reasons, may be an unsuitable solution. Were I in your shoes, rolling back to a configuration that worked in the past might be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, I have re-installed, and skipped the installation of the nb-javac plugin. I had forgotten that I did this on my older installations, until I re-read the post below. Everything is fine now.

[NetBeans plugin fails if nb-javac installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58638393/netbeans-plugin-fails-if-nb-javac-installed)

[What's "nb-javac" in Apache NetBeans?](https://blogs.apache.org/netbeans/entry/what-s-nb-javac-in)

Comment: Reduced the frequency of the problem, but not a complete solution.

Comment: Still happens too often. Given up and gone back to 12.3, and started looking for another IDE.

Comment: Problem has almost disappeared with 12.5 and Java 17.